# How to split an entire HTML page at a certain percentage

Tags: java, html

How do I split an entire HTML page at a certain percentage. I would like to split the page at 30% | 40% | 50% mark and I would still like the sentence above and below the split to make sense. I tried splitting the code by paragraphs or by the ending of a sentence. It is not very effective. What methodology should I use?

Comment: Any example, or code?

Comment: By make sense, do you mean the sentences should just be split at the end of each sentence, or should the paragraph/section as a whole still contain context?

Comment: End of a sentence would be fine. I am not sure how easy it would be to make it relevant to a context.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correct, you can solve this with div's.

This must be placed in your body.

```
<div>
    DIV A
</div>
<div>
    DIV B
</div>
```

The CSS.

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

You can change the with percentage if you add more div's or if you want one bigger then the other.